# How to get LogLiklihood value from logistic regression in R

Tags: r, likelihood-ratio

#### Question:

- Is it possible to get log liklihood values for my stepwise glms?

#### Context:

I am able to get a logliklihood value using lmer with the following model. My study involves unbalanced repeated females, two sites (females don't exchange between sites), 8 predictors, and a response.

```
    (glmfit1 <- lmer(Response ~ 1 + SITE + (1|SITE:FEMALE) + Variable A + Variable B +
                        Variable C, data = data))
```

Removing the repeated females and taking out the Site factor gives me this formula.

```
(lrfit1 <- glm(Response ~ 1+Variable A + Variable B + Variable C, data = data))
summary (lrfit1) #just gives me p values for my variables and an AIC but NO LOGLIK.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `logLik(lrfit1)`?

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks... I checked this with other models that I knew the likelihood and it is correct.